# EXCEL: Calculate FREQUENCY only IF creteria is met

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have a series of data in EXCEL and I want to create histograms out of them. But I do not want to use all data, but only those that met a certain criteria. In my case, this means all data from column H that do not have a certain string in column J. Here's what I wrote:

```
= FREQUENCY(IF(NOT(J2:J399="CG")*NOT(J2:J399="CT");H2:H399);$A2:$A53)
```

All data that have CG or CT in column J return a value of 0 and thus the data set is corrupted. So, I changed the command to give me a value that could go outside my data range:

```
= FREQUENCY(IF(NOT(J2:J399="CG")*NOT(J2:J399="CT");H2:H399;999);$A2:$A53)
```

And then I disregard these values when I plot the data. Is there a prettier way to do it?

Comment: I tried your first formula on a small set of data and it seemed to ignore the ones that were set to false  by the IF statement - although it's not clear from the documentation on the FREQUENCY function whether it is supposed to ignore TRUE/FALSE values or not. Can you give an example of some of your data and actual/expected result plz?

Comment: The examples here https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-8d9a69b3-b867-490e-82e0-a929fbc1e273 actually use "" to indicate values that should be ignored - FREQUENCY definitely ignores text values and blank cells.

Comment: Thank you, it seems that the "" value does the trick!